# can't hook JQuery quickSearch to the table - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use quickSearch from http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/ website. I don't know how to hook to the table so I hoping someone could be kind enough to help me here. I am using VS 2010 MVC 3, in C#, ADO.NET. Thanks in advance. I had a look at related question on the website, if there is a technical gitch? Is there alternative solution? Thanks in advance.

View file Index.cshtml looks like this...

Edited

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
 $("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({ widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra'], 
   sortList: [[0, 0]] })
   .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), size: $(".pagesize 
   option:selected").val() });
   });  
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () 
        {
          $('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {selector:'th'});
        }
       );
   </script>
   </p>
   <table  class="tablesorter">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also it could solve any code organisation problems if you are to wrap the JQuery statement in this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {         selector: 'th'     });
});
```

Also the table quick search plugin i use is [JQuery table search plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/uiTableFilter), it works well and if you just take a quick look at the demo it is rather easy to implement and does not clash with most other JQuery table plugins.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Linkgoron. Got it working after a week of struggle.Yes the script was placed way too early so I put in the tablesorter script. Also I need to use id as well. I was struggling because my lack of knowledge in script.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used QuickSearch before, and I'm not sure if it'll solve all of your problems, but as a start it appears that you've put your first script element too early in your document.

You need to put it after the other script elements.

this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$('input#search').quicksearch('table tbody tr', {         selector: 'th'     }); 
</script>
```

should appear after the the jquery script, and the quicksearch script elements. If you include it before, the browser doesn't know what $ and $(selector).quicksearch is.

btw: this:'input#search' selector is not needed. 
you can use the #search selector to same effect, becuase searching by id is a one command in JS.

Comment: Thanks Alex and Linkgoron. Got it working after a week of struggle.Yes the script was placed way too early so I put in the tablesorter script. Also I need to use id as well. I was struggling because my lack of knowledge in script.